# ¿Como hacer un select dinamico en laravel 5.7 laravel collective?

Tags: php, laravel

Veran tengo un formulario de registro a mi tabla `Inmueble`, y uno de los campos es su ubicación, la `ubicacion` también es una tabla en mi base de datos, los campos de la tabla `ubicacion` son `id` y `nombre`, necesito que en el select aparezca el `nombre`, y el valor que envié sea el `id`, pero no se como hacerlo en laravel collective.

Actualmente mi código en el controller es el siguiente:

```
$ubicaciones= Ubicacion::pluck('nombre', 'id');
```

La estoy recibiendo en la vista y la estoy mostrando de esta forma

```
{!! Form:: select('ubicacion', $ubicaciones, null, ['class' => 'select  ph9  sm10  md10  lg10', 'placeholder' => 'Ubicación']) !!}
```

Pero en este momento al registrar toda la información en el formulario y dar al botón de registro, laravel me da el error de registro diciendo que el campo de ubicación esta nulo, por lo que no se que hacer.

Comment: En laravel collective recibe un `array` el cual lo puedes obtener usando `pluck` de eloquent, para obtener mejores respuestas edita tu pregunta y agrega mas información como el codigo por ejemplo

Comment: Te entiendo, sucede que estoy usando ese pluck, dicha linea es así:

$ubicaciones= Ubicacion::pluck('nombre', 'id');

Pero el problema es que al registrar darle registrar al formulario, me dice que la columna donde va ese id se encuentra vacio, pero no se por que

Comment: Comprobaste que el request lleva los datos correctamente a la función de registro?

Comment: Que datos debería llevar? Mi request  tiene este dato: $inmueble->id_ubicacion = $request->input('id_ubicacion');
Pero no se que error habria, antes de poner el select (cuando era un input y escribia manualmente el id de la ubicacion) funcionaba perfectamente.

Comment: Lo que veo es que en tu formulario lo llamas `ubicacion` y cuando guardas lo estas llamando `id_ubicacion`, por lo cual no encuentra un valor para ese input, tienen que llamarse de la misma forma

Comment: Si, tienes razón, era eso, ya lo solucione, muchas gracias, si quieres la puntuación, escribe la respuesta y con gusto la doy

Answer (score 1):

En laravel collective es:

```
{!! Form::select('ubicacion', $ubicaciones, null, ['class' => 'ubicacion', 'id' =>'ubicacion']) !!}
```

En donde $ubicaciones contiene todas las ubicaciones que vas a listar.

Comment: ¿cuál es la diferencia entre este código y el de la pregunta?

Comment: Por lo que leí en la documentación de laravel collective, el ['class' => 'ubicacion', 'id' =>'ubicacion'] seria para darle diseño, es decir, el class es el class de html o css

Comment: La pregunta la respondí ayer antes de que la editaran, es por eso que escribí esta respuesta, por que la pregunta estaba sin el código de ejemplo